# Pandas Dataframe - list of dicts to seperate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, df, which has a column which is a list of dictionaries:

```
index action
0     [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'}{'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '1'}]
1     [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '1'}, {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '1'}]
2     [{'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '23'}, {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '23'}, {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '23'}]
```

I want to be able to extract the value from each dictionary and attribute it to its own column e.g.

```
index action_landing_page_view action_link_click action_page_engagement action_post_engagement action_video_view
0     1                        1                 1                      1                      0
1     1                        1                 1                      1                      0
2     0                        0                 23                     23                     23
```

I have tried `df.apply(pd.Series)` which splits out the `dicts` into seperate columns but with no column headers.

The dictionaries that are in my original dataframe do not follow the same order. e.g. the first dict for in row 1 starts with action_type "landing_page_view" whereas row 3 starts with "video_view".

Is it possible to attribute values to different columns based on the action_type in the dictionary?

Comment: how did you create this dataframe? i think tasks like this are best done at dataframe instatiation, not after the fact

Comment: made a call to the facebook marketing api which returns some json. then i used json_normalize to create this dataframe.

Comment: I recommend posting the JSON then

Answer (score 0):

You should first extract key-values for column name and column values, then constructing a dataframe based on them.
(I think from the very first place it does not make sense to have such dictionaries. It makes sense to have them like this: `{'landing_page_view': 1}`)

```
index_action_extracted = [{} for i in range(len(index_action))]

for i in range(len(index_action)):
    list_ = index_action[i]
    for dict_ in list_:
        column_name = dict_['action_type']
        column_value = dict_['value']
        index_action_extracted[i].update({column_name: column_value})

df = pd.DataFrame(index_action_extracted).fillna(0)
```

In `index_action_extracted` we are removing redundant keys `'action_type'` and `'value'` and build a dictionary without those keys.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using list comprehensions:

```py
pd.DataFrame(
    [{e['action_type']: e['value']
      for e in l}
     for l in list(df['action'])]
).fillna(0)
```

Notice that I reconstructed your dataframe as follow:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[
    [
        {'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '1'},
        {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'},
        {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '1'},
        {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '1'},
    ],
    [
        {'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '1'},
        {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'},
        {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '1'},
        {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '1'},
    ],
    [
        {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '23'},
        {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '23'},
        {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '23'},
    ]]]
)
df = df.transpose()
df = df[0].rename('action')
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I return a list of dictionary items and then I map the dictionary items into the dataframe then transpose the dataframe

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([
    [
    {'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '1'},
    {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'},
    {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '1'},
    {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '1'},
],
[
    {'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value': '1'},
    {'action_type': 'link_click', 'value': '1'},
    {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '1'},
    {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '1'},
],
[
    {'action_type': 'video_view', 'value': '23'},
    {'action_type': 'page_engagement', 'value': '23'},
    {'action_type': 'post_engagement', 'value': '23'},
]
])

df2=pd.DataFrame(columns=['action_type','value'])
for key,dictList in df.iterrows():
    for key, dictAction in dictList.items():  #returns tuple (index, dict)
    #print(dictAction)
        if (dictAction is None)==False:
        
            keys=dictAction.keys()
            index=len(df2)
            for key in keys:
               value=dictAction[key]
               df2.loc[index,key]=value

df2=df2.T
print(df2.head())
```